# Trying to add column in empty and existing table in postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have a project to create dynamic tables with columns

```
   $addThese = array();

    foreach ($fields['columns'] as $columnNew){

        $add = true;

        foreach ($structureOld['columns'] as $columnOld) {

            // Column exists
            if ($columnOld['originalName'] == $columnNew['originalName'])
                $add = false;

        }

        // No match, add column
        if ($add)
            $addThese[] = $columnNew;


    }

    Schema::connection('pgsql')->table($tableName, function($table) use ($addThese){

        foreach ($addThese as $column)


            $table->$column['originalType']($column['originalName'])->nullable();


    });
```

this code gives error array to string conversion on **                $table->$column'originalType'->nullable();
**
 and when altering code like this

```
Schema::connection('pgsql')->table($tableName, function($table) use ($addThese){

            foreach ($addThese as $column)

    $val = $column['originalType'].'("'.$column['originalName'].'")->nullable()';
           $table->$val;
```

*gives error*

> [ErrorException]
>   Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::
>   $string(name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside your foreach() loop:

```
$table->{$column['originalType']}($column['originalName'])->nullable();
```